# add add another jsp on click of button in dojo

Tags: dojo

I am developing web application using dojo, I am able to add one jsp within another jsp on click of button but problem is dojo component are not display it gives an error
"Error undefined running custom onLoad code: This deferred has already been resolved ContentPane.js:443
declare._onLoadHandler ContentPane.js:443"
I am adding jsp onclick of button using following code

```
      var div = dijit.byId("centerDiv");
      div.href = "../adminController/document";
      div.refresh();
```

and my jsp page contain simple content pan

```
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region:'top'"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The message "This deferred has already been resolved" is key here.  It looks like either your code is trying to resolve the same deferred more than once, which isn't allowed, or the way you've written your code, it's causing Dojo to try to resolve a deferred more than once.  Have you tried stepping through using your browser's development tool (e.g., Firebug)?